# I have wrong route in laravel

Tags: laravel

I get data from Search and when i want to store/create again, its show "pages not found"

Controller Search

```
public function searchGuest(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('q');

    if ($q != "") {
        $guests = Guest::where('guestsid', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->whereIn('id_status', [2])
            ->paginate(5);

        if (count($guests) > 0) {
            $lokasis = Lokasi::all();
            return view('guests.guestsId', compact('guests', 'lokasis'));
        } else {
            return view('guests.searchNotFound');
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{ action('GuestController@store') }}" method="post" id="myform">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset>
```

and when i click submit button show this page
[image]

but form already get data, but still /searchGuest, in this pict is must /guestsId right?
[image]

Comment: did you set post method in routes file?

Comment: i think it must to 127.0.0.1:8000/guests/guestsId like in picture, not /searchGuest

Comment: what is the relationship between `GuestController@store` and this controller method, `searchGuest`, that you are showing?  we don't know how your routes relate to these methods

Comment: GuestController@Store for insert data, and searchGuest for search data, and the problem is when i search it displays the form and data already get, but when i click submit button, it displays first pict

Comment: can you provide the route definition for these 2 routes

Answer (score 0):

check if query returns any results otherwise check your query dd(DB::getQueryLog());